# Error: package has no installation candidate

Tags: installation, package-management

I want to [install nautilus-open-terminal](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/05/13/nautilus-open-terminal-terminal-quick-launch/) on my 64 bit Lucid Lynx and I'm getting this:

```
antonio@antonio-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nautilus-open-terminal is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nautilus-open-terminal' has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package is available, and you can find it at http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/nautilus-open-terminal
There might have been a recent update, and you may have to update your APT cache.

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try to install again.

If all fail, you can get the .deb package for AMD64 from the same URL above and install manually. You can install manually if you double-click on the downloaded .deb file.