# Ubuntu 17.04 stuck on grub window while booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have 17.04 server. And windows also.

I installed bootrepair and clicked to do a repair. I then restarted and now there is no way to go to OS select screen. It is stuck on the grub terminal.

How can i fix this?

I just wanted to install locales because it was giving this error

[Error: package has no installation candidate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23898/error-package-has-no-installation-candidate)

I did everything to fix that locales but I could not so I repaired to see if it would work but instead I broke it :(

i dont have usb now. Is there any chance to do without it?

Comment: You may be able to manually boot. But command with separate /boot is slightly different as set root is to /boot partition and linux line is to main install partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655027#655027 But much better to always have a live installer to use as repair disk.https://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: when i do ls, i see ``(hdo)(hd0,msdos1)(hd1)(hd1,msdos1)(lvm/xxx-vg-swap_1)(lvm/xx-vg-root)`` when i write set, a lot of thingss come, not the ones in there

Comment: Since  you are showing LVM, then is it also an encrypted install? Easiest is just then to erase drive, reinstall and restore all  your data from you backup. With encrypted installs you have to have very good backups whether Linux or Windows.

Comment: @oldfred what about usb, cant i recover with usb? i dont know if it is encrypted

Comment: You had to choose encryption which uses LVM or choose LVM as neither is the standard install. If encrypted you have to also give a passphrase when booting. I have never used LVM, so do not know details. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm and: First part of this is about mounting: How to: Mount & Resize an Encrypted Partition (LUKS) also mount for repairs
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=4530641

Comment: I installed grub. i can see now my OS windows and ubuntu. but it cant login. It stucks at OS screen

Comment: What video card/chip? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it